# How to slice rows between first and last row in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I use `loc` to slice everything between first and last row of following pandas `DataFrame`?

**Input:**

```
 id  text  
 0   A    
 1   B    
 2   C    
 3   D
```

**Output:**

```
| id | text | 
|----|------|
| 1  | B    |
| 2  | C    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Selecting rows

Use

```
df.iloc[1:-1]   # similar to df.iloc[1:3]

   id text
1   1    B
2   2    C
```

To slice all rows by position between 0 and -1 (exclusive).

---

#### Assigning to an existing column

Since `iloc` expects positional values, if you need to assign back, pass the column position as the second argument in this manner:

```
df.iloc[1:-1, df.columns.get_loc('text')] = 'Test'    
df

   id  text
0   0     A
1   1  Test
2   2  Test
3   3     D
```

---

#### Assigning to a new column

Since your index values are numeric, you can simplify the options above (as a special case):

```
df.loc[1:2, 'text'] = 'Test'  # note the slice is `1:2`, not `1:3` or `1:-1`
```

In the case of `loc`, the ending slice is *inclusive*. If you don't know at runtime what your index labels will be, you can generalise using:

```
# Generalized solution
df.loc[df.index[1]:df.index[-2], 'text'] = 'Test'
```

The solution above leaves NaNs to unassigned rows. To assign values to all rows, one option would be to use `fillna` from the solution above. But we can optimize a bit using `np.where` or a more specific expression that depends on your problem.